# SQLite get MAX value BETWEEN range with some null fields

Tags: sqlite, null, max

I have a table, two columns some rows:

```
c1 | c2

--------

10 | 90

11 | 89.5

12 | 89

13 | 87

14 | null

15 | 86
```

I want to get the MAX value of column c2 but only between c1's values 12 and 15
I try with:

```
SELECT MAX(IFNULL(c2, 0)) AS max_value FROM mytable WHERE data BETWEEN 12 AND 15
```

but not working. Is there a way to ignore the null value ?

Comment: why it isn't working? MAX() will automatically skip null values, `SELECT MAX(c2) FROM tablename WHERE c1 BETWEEN 12 AND 15;` should be fine

Comment: I want the query to return 89

if I use: SELECT MAX(c2) AS max_value FROM mytable ...
I get "". Looks like NULL is the MAX value.

Comment: please see this fiddle ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/57bc7/4 it returns 89 which is correct

Comment: `WHERE data BETWEEN 12 AND 15` is it correct? shouldn't it be `WHERE c1 BETWEEN 12 AND 15`? maybe that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAX aggregated function will automatically skip null values, so the following query should be fine:

```
SELECT MAX(c2) FROM tablename WHERE c1 BETWEEN 12 AND 15;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/57bc7/4). I see your where condition is

```
WHERE data BETWEEN 12 AND 15
```

are you sure you are applying the WHERE clause to the correct column? I think you need to change it to:

```
WHERE c1 BETWEEN 12 AND 15
```

Comment: My mistake, the code was writing "" instead of null. I was thinking it was null because Chrome resources doesn't make difference from showing "" and null fields. My fault. Thanks anyway. Knowing the query was ok, I found the bug.

Comment: Great tool that sqlfiddle.com there!

Thanks for the support, again!

My case http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d1f4e/2

Answer (score 1):

"The max() aggregate function returns the maximum value of all values in the group. The maximum value is the value that would be returned last in an ORDER BY on the same column. Aggregate max() returns NULL if and only if there are no non-NULL values in the group." - http://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Assumed, you have no negatives and you don't want NULL to be 0, You can simply use

```
SELECT MAX(c2) AS max_value FROM mytable ...
```

If all rows for c2 are null, max(c2) will return null

Comment: Wooops you're right!

Sorry Guys bug in my code, field was set to "" so no visible difference in the table from Chrome resources.

Query works, just add WHERE c2 IS NOT '' in the query and it works.

So yes... right answer would be: Are you sure the field is NULL ?!